# JavaScript callback doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

It's probably a simple problem, but I have the following function:

```
addValues();
function addValues() {
    addObsToMap(function() {
        addMeansToMap();
    });                 
}
```

They are defined as such:

```
function addObsToMap(callback) {
    console.log("addObsToMap");
    callback();
}                                                               

function addMeansToMap() {
    console.log("addMeansToMap");   
}
```

What I want to do is call 'addObsToMap' before calling 'addMeansToMap', but that's not happening with the current code, as 'addMeansToMap' is currently being returned before 'addObsToMap'. What am I missing?

Comment: *that's not happening with the current code.* - so what is actually happening with the code? Do you receive some errors? Is this `addObsToMap` function being even called?

Comment: You can pass `addMeansToMap` instead of `function () { addMeansToMap() }`

Comment: That code works for me

Comment: @Kinduser I've updated the OP. Means() gets called before Obs().

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure? In js fiddle addobs is done first

https://jsfiddle.net/moym1n8c/

```
console.log('first');
addValues();
```

results in :

```
first
addobjstomap
addmeanstomap
```

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: Edited the answer to put result, but didn't do anything except run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work perfectly fine..

But different browsers and different versions might have different implementations.

A change i would make would be to just pass the "addMeansToMap" function as the callback, instead of creating a new function to execute it.

```js
addValues();
function addValues() {
    addObsToMap(addMeansToMap);                 
}

function addObsToMap(callback) {
    console.log("addObsToMap");
    callback();
}                                                               

function addMeansToMap() {
    console.log("addMeansToMap");   
}
```

This way, if wanted, we can also more easily pass data from addObsToMap to addMeansToMap without needing a global variable.

```js
    addValues();
    function addValues() {
        addObsToMap(addMeansToMap);                 
    }

    function addObsToMap(callback) {
        console.log("addObsToMap");
        callback("addMeansToMap");
    }                                                               

    function addMeansToMap(arg) {
        console.log(arg); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hard Coded**
`addMeansToMap();` is called when you call your other function instead of passing it as a callback. To fix this just call `addMeansToMap();` from the other function after the other code has executed.

```
function addObsToMap() {
     console.log("addObsToMap");   
     addMeansToMap();
} 

function addMeansToMap(){ 
     console.log("addMeansToMap");
}
```

**Using Parametric Callback**
Note also that you have not actually passed the function in as a callback when you call the function.

```
addValues(); 
function addValues(){ 
    addObsToMap(addMeansToMap);
}
```

The above way would work keeping the original Obs and Means functions the same.

Comment: What if he wants to call a parametric callback, as he does? You just hard-coded it, which works, but is not the full solution.

Comment: you never called callback?

Comment: Fixed that, hadn't noticed I'd left that in my hardcoded functions. Sorry.